# How to zip up folder contents and save the zip files inside the original folders

Tags: windows, zip

I have a large folder containing a lot of folders. How can I zip up the contents of each of the subfolders, and save the resulting zip files inside the respective subfolders for which each archive was made? For example, I would want this

```
folder1
  file1.mp4
  file2.mp4
  file3.mp4
folder2
  file12.mp4
  file13.mp4
  file17.mp4
```

to become like this

```
folder1
  file1.mp4
  file2.mp4
  file3.mp4
  folder1.zip
folder2
  file12.mp4
  file13.mp4
  file17.mp4
  folder2.zip
```

Comment: Does the zipfile itself has to include that folder as well? Meaning that if you open the zipfile with an archiver, you first see folder1, also if you extract the archive it will create that folder first?

Comment: No. It isn't necessary. I don't care about it. All i want the zip file to be inside the folder.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! A couple questions for you: in the "after" example, should the first time it says `folder2.zip` actually just say `folder2`? And do you care what program you use to get this done, or do you just care about results? If just results, you might be better off removing the 7-zip, winrar and winzip tags.

Comment: Its folder2 actually i've corrected it now. Yes, I dont care about the program used i just care about results. Thanks for pointing the mistake. :)